# SSH Tunnel not allowing me to SSH through it

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, debian, tunnel

I have set up remote server that automatically connects back to local server via `autossh`:

> sudo autossh -M 10984 -N -f -o "PubkeyAuthentication=yes" -o "PasswordAuthentication=no" -i /root/.ssh/nopwd -R 6666:localhost:22 @ -p  &

I have set up the autossh command above in rc.local:

`#!/bin/sh -e
    #
    #
    # This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
    # Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
    # value on error.
    #
    # In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
    # bits.
    #
    # By default this script does nothing.
    autossh -M 10984 -N -f -o "PubkeyAuthentication=yes" -o 
    "PasswordAuthentication=no" -i /root/.ssh/nopwd -R 6666:localhost:22

    <username>@<domain> -p portNumber &
    exit 0`

Then I created a rc-local service:
    `sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service
    #add the following lines
    [Unit]
    Description=/etc/rc.local Compatibility
    ConditionPathExists=/etc/rc.local
    [Service]
    Type=forking
    ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start
    TimeoutSec=0
    StandardOutput=tty
    RemainAfterExit=yes
    SysVStartPriority=99
    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target`

Then I told the service to run on each boot:

> sudo systemctl enable rc-local

The remote server connects back via ssh on boot then maintains the connection successfully:

> Netstat shows:
>       tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6666            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      22542/sshd

Now I attempt to connect to 6666 on my local server:

> ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p 6666

I get the following error:
    ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

When I ssh with the -vvv option set I get the following debug logs:

```
# ssh -vvv 127.0.0.1 -p 6666
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Debian-2, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "127.0.0.1" port 6666
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 6666.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Debian-2
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

However, if I kill the ssh connection on both ends (local, and remote). And then re-establish the reverse ssh connection from the remote server:

> autossh -M 10984 -N -f -o "PubkeyAuthentication=yes" -o        "PasswordAuthentication=no" -i /root/.ssh/nopwd -R 6666:localhost:22      @ -p portNumber &

The tunnel is built successfully. And I can then ssh through 127.0.0.1 -p 6666 successfully.

> ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p 6666
>       Last login: Sun Dec 17 10:50:29 2017 from ::1

I need this work on boot without manual intervention. What am I doing wrong?